# Alternative to "sort | uniq -c | sort -n"

Tags: command-line-interface

I've been doing `| sort | uniq -c | sort -n` for years!  Just wondering if somewhere buried in the command stack that people have been updating for years if there is a simple alternative.

Comment: What do you want to achive? Any kind of improvement or just type less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe name it `quniqsort`? Mindset of Unix: keeping it simple and chaining small things together.

```
#/bin/sh
sort < /dev/stdin | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: I would probably change this to -- sort $* | uniq -c | sort -n since then the script can take optional arguments.

Comment: @koblas -- I've started using `alias sus='sort | uniq -c | sort -n'` which you can remember easily given Among Us :)

Comment: `sort "$@"` preserves the word boundaries and thus is better than `sort $*` (at least in bash).